# What does parameter max_newidle_lb_cost actually mean?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, scheduling

What this parameter of scheduling domain mean?

e.g. `kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain0.max_newidle_lb_cost = 11372`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`max_newidle_lb_cost` tracks the maximum cost, per domain, of idle load balancing. [The patch introducing `max_newidle_lb_cost`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=9bd721c55c8a886b938a45198aab0ccb52f1f7fa) describes the process as follows:

> [w]e keep track of the max cost we spend doing idle load balancing
> for each sched domain. If the avg time the CPU remains idle is less then the
> time we have already spent on idle balancing + the max cost of idle balancing
> in the sched domain, then we don't continue to attempt the balance. We also
> keep a per rq variable, max_idle_balance_cost, which keeps track of the max
> time spent on newidle load balances throughout all its domains so that we can
> determine the avg_idle's max value.
>
> By using the max, we avoid overrunning the average. This further reduces the
> chance we attempt balancing when the CPU is not idle for longer than the cost
> to balance.

The general idea is that there’s no point in load balancing idle CPUs if they stay idle for less time than the cost of load balancing — *i.e.* they would naturally be given work to do in less time than it would take to load balance.